# How to collect logs from Uniswap V2: Router 2?

Tags: blockchain, json-rpc

I have a problem with collecting logs from [Uniswap router contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d).
I use json_rpc [eth_getlogs](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_getlogs)
When I call the method I receive nothing.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getLogs","params":[{"topics":[],"fromBlock":"earliest","toBlock":"latest","address":["0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d"]}],"id":0}'
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: seems like Uni router doesn't have its own events

Comment: @belbix did you figure out how to get the log events ?

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime sure, use this http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/Ethereum.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/eth_getLogs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong.

I looked through the code for the Router contract and it just seems like the contract *declares* but never **emits** its events.

#### Let's look for emissions of the `Swap()` event.

The event is declared on `line 46` (see [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d#code#L46)) at:

```
event Swap(
        address indexed sender,
        uint amount0In,
        uint amount1In,
        uint amount0Out,
        uint amount1Out,
        address indexed to
    );
```

An emission of this event would look something like:

```
Swap(sender, amount0In, amount1In,amount0Out,amount1Out, to)
```

but you can just search the contract for any other instance of Swap() and there simply isn't.

Same is true for all their other declared events `Burn()`, `Mint()`, `Sync()`, etc. Declared but never emitted.

#### Compare this with the `Transfer()` event of another frequently used contract like USDT:

This event is declared on `line 86` (see [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7#contracts)) at:

```
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
```

And gets emitted a few times:

```
Transfer(msg.sender, owner, fee); // Line 136
Transfer(msg.sender, _to, sendAmount); // Line 138
Transfer(_from, owner, fee); // Line 189
Transfer(_from, _to, sendAmount); // Line 191
```

### In short:

Events need to be declared and emitted. Uniswap's Router for some reason only declares them but never emits them, hence you will find no logs for any topic.